# How to show zipcode wise cash on delivery option in Product description Front end page and billing tab

Tags: magento

Please Help me. I want to the show particular area only will accept cash on delivery option, in product description page and also in billing page in magento. I am beginner pls help me as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

Magento is a bit terrifying for beginners lol. You can turn on template path hints to find out where files are located. Follow instructions here

http://www.pauldonnelly.net/magento-turning-on-template-path-hints/